# To Access jTextArea inside main()

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to access jTextArea inside main(), but got an error stating that, `"Non-static members cannot be accessed in static context"`. Hence i accessed in the following way: (using netbeans)

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           new UserInterface().setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    sample ss=new sample();
    System.out.println("Inside Main()");
    ss.display("Happy");
}

class sample 
{
    void display(String message)
    {

        UserInterface ui=new UserInterface();
        System.out.println("inside sample:"+message);
        ui.jTextArea2.append(message);
        String aa=ui.jTextArea2.getText();
        System.out.println("Content of JTextArea2:"+aa);
    }
}
```

I've declared the variable as: `public javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea2;`

I got the following output:

Inside Main()

inside sample:Happy

Content of JTextArea2:Happy

But the problem is: the message is not displayed in jTextArea2 in GUI.

Comment: Are you sure that jTextArea displayed in UI is refrenced by jTtestArea2?

Answer (score 2):

You've created two different references to your `UserInterface`...

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       // Here's one...
       new UserInterface().setVisible(true);
    }
});

//...

void display(String message)
{
    // And here's another
    UserInterface ui=new UserInterface();
```

Now these two references have nothing to do with each other and any modification to one won't effect the other.

If you didn't something like:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            UserInterface ui = new UserInterface();
            ui.jTextArea2.append(message);
            ui.setVisible(true)
        }
    });
}
```

You should find that it works.

**UPDATE**

Loading classes from the `public static void main(String[] agrs)` is done all the time, be a bit hard to get anything done other wise ;)

```
public class UserInterface extends javax.swing.JFrame { 
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() {
                UserInterface ui = new UserInterface();
                // Happy interactions :D
            } 
        }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, actually I've written the main() function within UserInterface class. The code is as follows: `code` public class UserInterface extends javax.swing.JFrame { public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { ....... } }); }                                                                    So, How can i create an object called ui inside run()?